# Excel VBA: To store 'a word in a string' into a variable if that word is there in an array of strings

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose my string is

```
my_string="MY PET IS CAT "
```

I have an array also

```
my_animals=Array ("CAT","DOG","LION")
```

Since one of the string in array (CAT) is there in my_string, I want to have CAT in a variable.

How can we make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim my_string As String, my_animals As Variant, element As Variant, variable as String
my_string = "MY PET IS CAT "

my_animals = Array("CAT", "DOG", "LION")

For Each element In my_animals
  If InStr(my_string, element) Then
  variable = element
  End If
Next element
```

Comment: I assume the OP wants a variable for *each* element of `my_animals` which is present in `my_string`. This will just overwrite `variable` each time.

Comment: @LondonRob well, i read "Since one of the string in array"... i supposed that "one of the..." means he can find just one element of the array. let's see if he needs further assistance

Comment: This is what I wanted. TY. @LondonRob TY for your concern.

Comment: Pleasure was all mine!

Answer (score 2):

Just for posterity, here's a (not particularly brilliant, but functional) way of adding *any* elements of `my_animals` which were found in `my_string`:

```
Public Sub FindAnimals

    dim my_string as String
    dim my_animals as Variant
    dim found(0) as String
    dim animal as String

    my_string="MY PETS ARE CAT AND LION"
    my_animals=Array ("CAT","DOG","LION")

    For Each animal in my_animals
       If InStr(my_string, animal) Then
           found(UBound(found)) = animal
           ReDim Preserve found(UBound(found) + 1)
       End If
    Next animal

End Sub
```

After running, `found` will be an array of `String`s with three elements:

- `"CAT"`
- `"LION"`
- `""`

As I said, it's not the greatest method the world has ever seen, but it might be  a starting point for something better.